How do I listen to checkpoints/savepoint creation in Flink?
I have a flink app, in which I want to listen to checkpoint/savepoint creation events. How do I do that?
I could not find any way to hook a listener for checkpoints in StreamExecutionEnvironment.

There's a callback available to each operator that you hook into by implementing the CheckpointListener interface. You are probably wanting to implement the notifyCheckpointComplete() method.

Thank you! Where do I register this listener?

Have your source, sink, or process function, etc, implement CheckpointListener, and then define notifyCheckpointComplete in that function class.

Flink always calls this method on every operator. You are replacing the default implementation with one of your own.
